# Iterate through a list of properties in object in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have this object with arrays:

```
"{
    "Drivers":[
        {
            "Id":"41ba341a-e50f-4878-b55e-6c96ef5027b0",
            "FirstName":"John",
            "LastName":"David",
            "MiddleName":"Smity",
            "Party":{
                "Id":"12rtb67-fa45-4e77-998c-123fgyh764",
                "Name":"The Smith Family",
                "CustomerId":"01d84752-ad12-4dfa-af63-65d12052a161"
            }
        },
        {
            "Id":"f37ff0c7-294d-43d1-a790-11af1f6f3e91",
            "FirstName":"John",
            "LastName":"Smith",
            "MiddleName":"David",
            "Party":{
                "Id":"f2a82558-fa45-4e77-998c-29160f30f9f6",
                "Name":"The Smith Family",
                "CustomerId":"01d84752-ad12-4dfa-af63-65d12052a161"
            }
        }
    ]
}"
```

I want to iterate through the Drivers objects and display the values in angularjs foreach.

This is what I'm trying:

```
<table data-ng-controller="DriverController">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody data-ng-repeat="driver in Drivers.Drivers">
    <tr>
      <td>{{driver.FirstName}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

it didn't help.

I also tried:

```
<table data-ng-controller="DriverController">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody data-ng-repeat="driver in Drivers">
    <tr>
      <td>{{driver.FirstName}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

But I got the same result, no data shown on the screen.

How can I iterate through the properties of the array and display the results in a table as I'm trying in the example?

Comment: `"{"Drivers":[{"Id":"4` what variable is being set equal to this object?

Comment: Also, that is a string. Just noticed when I was editting. Try parsing it?

Comment: Yep, that should be valid JSON so you can do JSON.parse on the string to turn it into a JS object.

Comment: use angular.fromJson to first parse the data into a valid json object.. check `Drivers.length` it should be greater than zero

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON was a string in the example. If that is how you are receiving it from the server, you will need to parse it. Barring that, your code works in this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/x2IJRCUUTqpYnombadzn?p=preview

```
<table data-ng-controller="DriverController">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Name</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody data-ng-repeat="driver in drivers.Drivers">
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{driver.FirstName}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>


$scope.drivers = {
    "Drivers":[
        {
            "Id":"41ba341a-e50f-4878-b55e-6c96ef5027b0",
            "FirstName":"John",
            "LastName":"David",
            "MiddleName":"Smity",
            "Party":{
                "Id":"12rtb67-fa45-4e77-998c-123fgyh764",
                "Name":"The Smith Family",
                "CustomerId":"01d84752-ad12-4dfa-af63-65d12052a161"
            }
        },
        {
            "Id":"f37ff0c7-294d-43d1-a790-11af1f6f3e91",
            "FirstName":"John",
            "LastName":"Smith",
            "MiddleName":"David",
            "Party":{
                "Id":"f2a82558-fa45-4e77-998c-29160f30f9f6",
                "Name":"The Smith Family",
                "CustomerId":"01d84752-ad12-4dfa-af63-65d12052a161"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
            $scope.Drivers =
           [
                {
                    "Id": "41ba341a-e50f-4878-b55e-6c96ef5027b0",
                    "FirstName": "John",
                    "LastName": "David",
                    "MiddleName": "Smity",
                    "Party": {
                        "Id": "12rtb67-fa45-4e77-998c-123fgyh764",
                        "Name": "The Smith Family",
                        "CustomerId": "01d84752-ad12-4dfa-af63-65d12052a161"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "Id": "f37ff0c7-294d-43d1-a790-11af1f6f3e91",
                    "FirstName": "John",
                    "LastName": "Smith",
                    "MiddleName": "David",
                    "Party": {
                        "Id": "f2a82558-fa45-4e77-998c-29160f30f9f6",
                        "Name": "The Smith Family",
                        "CustomerId": "01d84752-ad12-4dfa-af63-65d12052a161"
                    }
                }
           ];

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-ng-repeat="driver in Drivers">
            <tr>
                <td>{{driver.FirstName}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks, for some reason the array or better said the string which hold the array is not working as expected. I'm not sure what do I need to do the transition from a string to json array.